# CodeIgniter error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to Select data from the datatbase but I get this error:

```
  A PHP Error was encountered        
    Severity: Warning
    Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
    Filename: controllers/hello.php
    Line Number: 24
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
    // system/application/controllers/hello.php

    class Hello extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
       }

       function show_data() {

            $query = $this->load->model('user');
            foreach ($query->result() as $value) {
                echo $value -> username;
                echo $value -> password;
                echo $value -> first_name;
                echo $value -> last_name;
            }
       }
    }
?>
```

**Model:**

```
class User extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function show()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('user', 10);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

I'm looking at this tutorial: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller function should be like,

```
function show_data() {
    $this->load->model('user');
    $query = $this->user->show();
    foreach($query as $value) {
        echo $value->username;
        echo $value->password;
        echo $value->first_name;
        echo $value->last_name;
    }
}
```

Check [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model) on how to load a model.

Comment: I'll just add that it's kinda too basic mistake, so to avoid these in future, make sure you make the introduction tutorial on CI documentation, it's really helpful.

Comment: thanks, you know today I started with CI and all thinks at the begining are difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling $query->result() twice, once in model and once in loop, you should do it only once. That was just one mistake.

The other, more important is that you initiate the model (and asign it to variable, which is not needed, and is a bad practice), and you don't call the function from you model.

So first you have to initiate your model in controller (your function or in construct if you plan to use this model more often): $this->load->model('my_model');

Then you got to access the function that you want to use: $this->my_model->my_model_function()

Comment: I remove in foreach "->reult()" now I get this -> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/hello.php

Line Number: 24

Comment: Thanks for help problem is fixed.